# not able to add images to seeds.rb ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, cloudinary

I am trying to add images to my seeds.rb in my ruby on rails app. However the images do not save and I'm  not able to show them in my app. When I run rails db:seed, I do not get an error. I am using active storage.

I hope you can help me out!

[product-card.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA4qp.png)
[seeds.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrXhY.png)

Comment: are you using active storage to store images?

Comment: You don't need `image` column in your table

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of link screenshots

Comment: i have removed the images from the table, but that did not make a difference @mechnicov.

Comment: Yes i am using active_storage @MehmetAdilİstikbal

Comment: @greenglasses. Please post the code as text not an image

Answer (score 0):

You want to persist the record before you do the attaching. Here's an example from my seed file:

```
    person =
      FactoryBot.create(
        :person,
        account:,
        name: Faker::TvShows::FamilyGuy.unique.character
      )
    person.avatar.attach(
      filename: 'avatar.jpg',
      io: URI.open('https://api.lorem.space/image/face')
    )
```